# Mysql average all results from count

Tags: mysql

I am trying to average all of my results from the "Count" column however it is telling me that the column "Count" does not exist.

```
SELECT
    Date,
    COUNT(Date) as Count,
    a.Average
From Rundown
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT AVG(Count) AS Average, WorkOrder FROM Rundown
            ) AS a
            ON (Rundown.WorkOrder = a.WorkOrder)
WHERE Rundown.Date > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY Date
```

Results I am expecting

```
Date | Count | Average
2016-09-08 | 19 | 19
2016-09-09 | 20 | 19
2016-09-10 | 19 | 19
2016-09-12 | 17 | 19
```

Edit:

I ended up writing a second query to complete this for me

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(avg(a.Count)) as Average
FROM (
SELECT
    Date,
    COUNT(Date) as Count
From Rundown
    WHERE Rundown.Date > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 Day))
    AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY Date
    ) as a
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query  don't exist a column count

```
SELECT
  Date,
  COUNT(Date) as Count,
  a.Average
From Rundown
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT AVG(Count) AS Average, WorkOrder FROM Rundown
                     ^^ this column not exist 
          ) AS a
          ON (Rundown.WorkOrder = a.WorkOrder)
WHERE Rundown.Date > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY Date
```

you could use Count(Date)

```
SELECT
    Date,
    COUNT(Date) as Count,
    a.Average
From Rundown
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT AVG(Count(Date)) AS Average, WorkOrder FROM Rundown
            ) AS a
            ON (Rundown.WorkOrder = a.WorkOrder)
WHERE Rundown.Date > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY Date
```

And for group by

```
SELECT
    `Date`,
    COUNT(`Date`) as Count,
    a.Average
From Rundown
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT AVG(Count(`Date`)) AS Average, WorkOrder FROM Rundown
            GROUP BY WorkOrder
            ) AS a
            ON (Rundown.WorkOrder = a.WorkOrder)
WHERE Rundown.`Date` > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY `Date`
;
```

Comment: Never seen this error before with your query, #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: @JohnLang  obviuos  your error mask the group by problem  .. anyway i have update the answer ..

Comment: I still get the same error for both of your queries for some reason

Comment: `COUNT(Date)` is constant. And `AVG(constant) = constant` I dont think calculate what you want.

Comment: Could be because is a reserved  word so i have update the asnwer (last query)  using backtcs

Answer (score 0):

You dont have count for every date anywhere. So you calculate like this.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS Average, WorkOrder 
 FROM Rundown
 GROUP BY WorkOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

This Looks like a job for `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` but without a full schema, it is hard to tell. I *think* this is what you what:

```
SELECT
  Date,
  COUNT(*) / COUNT(Date) AS Count_or_Average
From Rundown
WHERE Rundown.Date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 Day
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY Date WITH ROLLUP
```

Where a NULL date is your average